# How to handle removing a relationship in JSON:API?

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, ember.js, json-api

We are currently developing a single page application using Ember and CakePHP. We use [JSON:API](http://jsonapi.org/) format for transmitting data.

However, when creating a relationship the client transmits the id. When removing the relationship Ember transmits the id as `null`.

But on the server side the `null` is not capturable, so we use an additional query parameter to indicate that it should be removed.

How can we achieve this (capture the `null` value) using CakePHP while still adhering to the JSON:API specification?

Alternatively, is there any other way to delete a relationship with the JSON:API spec or using Ember?

Comment: I do not think this is an opinion question because JSONAPI spec is strict. What do you mean by "null is not capturable"? The JSONAPI specification does indeed send null, so the front end is working as expected. One option you have is that you could send a non-Ember Data POST request that is formatted how your back end expects. You don't have to use Ember Data all the time. However your current solution is good because it does not break JSONAPI specification.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `capture the null value`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that this is best solved in the PHP side so I'm sure someone else would be better suited to answer this question. I am able to answer from the Ember side.

First thing I would like to say is that @handlebars is right in their comment: the main point is you **don't need to use ember-data for every request** if you don't want to.

What we mean by this is that you probably already have a situation where you are getting a bunch of models via ember-data using methods like:

```
this.get('store').findRecord('post', 1);
```

and you probably have a bunch of relationships setup already. If you want to delete a relationship and your backend API is not capable of following the [JSON:API specification](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating-to-one-relationships) then you can just create a specific endpoint that does this job.

To then execute a `DELETE` request to a specific endpoint then you can use the following code:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Controller.extend({
  ajax: service(),
  actions: {
    deleteRelationship(id) {
      this.get('ajax').request(`/posts/${id}/author`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This code is using [ember-ajax](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax) to make a direct call to the network.

**NOTE:** you have to be very careful with this approach. This will mean that your backend will get out of sync with ember-data and you will have to reload the post model in the frontend right after you have performed the delete:

```
store.findRecord('post', 1, { reload: true });
```

Because of some of the strange syncing behaviour I **highly recommend** that you update your backend to be able to follow the JSON:API spec and accept nulls to remove relationships.

Also if you want to see us discuss answering this question on Video you can see it here https://youtu.be/WKfq3dS73xg and here https://youtu.be/ExUtgatzZeI?t=25m54s